# DataGridView Selected Cell border showing wrong cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I currently am using a code to make a border for a selected cell.  Though I suspect with how I am implementing it I getting some visual problems.  For my application I have a dynamic number of tabs, each with its own DataGridView, so the following event is used by all grids:

```
    private void gridSelection_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage currentPage = tabs.SelectedTab;
        DataGridView currentGrid = currentPage.Controls[0] as DataGridView;
        if (currentGrid.Equals(sender))
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1 && currentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Selected)
            {
                using (Pen borderPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
                {
                    Rectangle rectDimensions = e.CellBounds;
                    rectDimensions.Width -= 2;
                    rectDimensions.Height -= 2;
                    rectDimensions.X = rectDimensions.Left + 1;
                    rectDimensions.Y = rectDimensions.Top + 1;

                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(borderPen, rectDimensions);

                    e.Handled = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

My issue came from changing tabs.  The selected cell on the tab that is selected still shows the cell from the previous tab.  The work around is that the user just needs to select a new cell and then everything returns to normal operation. (I would to show a visual but every cell is filled with very secret Intellectual Property for my company).

As can be seen in the code above I tried to make sure that the only grid firing off the event is the grid currently being displayed to the user. I even tried preventing the previous grid from firing the event with the tab_change event:

```
    private void tabChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage currentPage = tabs.SelectedTab;
        DataGridView currentGrid = currentPage.Controls[0] as DataGridView;
        currentGrid.CellPainting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(gridSelection_CellPainting);
        foreach (TabPage tab1 in tabs.TabPages)
        {
            if (!tab1.Equals(currentPage))
            {
                DataGridView otherGrid = operation.Controls[0] as DataGridView;
                otherGrid.CellPainting -= new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(gridSelection_CellPainting);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sadly, I'm still having it where I switch tabs and the selected cell in the selected tab visually shows the previous tabs selected cell.

I also found I may be able to recreate the problem with just one grid.  When I click a column header and the rows are then ordered by that column (default functionality), I noticed that the selected cell remains constant.

For a visual.  If I had the following as a column

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

And I have the cell with the value 3 selected when I clicked to order the column I would get

- 4
- 3
- 3
- 1

And when I change which cell is selected, I would then have the correct order of

- 4
- 3
- 2
- 1

I suspect the issue is something to do with a nuance the DrawRectangle function that I don't know about.  Anyone else seen this or resolved yet?

Thanks

EDIT:

For the updated, cleaner code.  Tabchange is pretty much empty now, it has some code I haven't shown, because if I comment it out it has no affect on my issue.

For cell painting:

```
    private void gridSelection_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage currentPage = tabs.SelectedTab;
        DataGridView currentGrid = currentPage.Controls[0] as DataGridView;
        if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1 && currentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Selected)
        {
            using (Pen borderPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
            {
                Rectangle rectDimensions = e.CellBounds;
                rectDimensions.Width -= 2;
                rectDimensions.Height -= 2;
                rectDimensions.X = rectDimensions.Left + 1;
                rectDimensions.Y = rectDimensions.Top + 1;

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(borderPen, rectDimensions);

                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

I needed to keep the currentGrid code as I need to verify the cell is selected.  The code I took this from expected the event to be tied to one grid only which could be called easily and not an event that would be tied to a dynamic number of grids.

EDIT EDIT:

[Image of cell showing visual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW9Fj.png)

I added an image that is cropped to hide IP content.  This is taken from a grid where the first column is blank, this after selecting a cell in a different tab that has different sizing.  As can be seen the selected cell on top has a border as intended but inside it is not blank but instead the image of another grid.

For issues inside the same grid here are some extra pictures:

[Correct descending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0276Q.png)

[After column header clicked to be ascending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlHMO.png)

[After changing which cell is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTYmI.png)

Comment: `currentGrid.CellPainting += ...` only add an event handler once.  That said, your first three lines in the CellPainting event look unnecessary.  The sender is the DataGridView that is painting — the current TabPage shouldn't matter.  If the grid isn't visible, the painting isn't going to be called.

Comment: Suspected as much as I continued to monkey with it.  I was just suspicious because I was getting visuals from a cell from a tab that was not visible.  And if the event truly only fires for visible DataGridView, then yeah no need for my attempts to remove and add event handlers.

Comment: If anyone has seen the comments, these are useful for cleaning up the code, but I had created all that ugly hacks to try and resolve the issue, so even with clean up I still have visual issues.  If anyone has seen or experienced these, any feedback on possible solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try posting the cleaned up version.  It's not clear why tabs are causing any issue.  Like I said, the hidden grids won't be painting anything, so you would have to explain how "getting visuals from a cell from a tab that was not visible" happens.

Comment: Will do when I get time tomorrow, the last section of my question points out that the same issue can be replicated with just one grid when re-ordering the rows based off of the default column header click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and experimenting, it appeared to me that whenever I used the graphics to paint a rectangle, the rectangle was cleanly painted each time, but the inside of the cell was just whatever was leftover from the last paint event for that cell.  It wasn't like it was doing the default paint of a cell and then painting a rectangle on top of it. i.e. I felt like I was overriding the normal paint event that would show a cell and it's values.

This would make sense, as I was overriding the default behavior to show the cell highlighted.  Which looking at my code, all it is doing is drawing a rectangle and should have noticed that it was not changing the color of the selected cell (default is blue). So my solution was simply to try and recreate the cell in it's entirety.

```
    private void gridSelection_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage currentPage = tabs.SelectedTab;
        DataGridView currentGrid = currentPage.Controls[0] as DataGridView;
        if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && e.RowIndex != -1 && currentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Selected)
        {
            using (Pen borderPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
            {
                Brush backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor);
                // Erase the cell.
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);

                Rectangle rectDimensions = e.CellBounds;
                rectDimensions.Width -= 2;
                rectDimensions.Height -= 2;
                rectDimensions.X = rectDimensions.Left + 1;
                rectDimensions.Y = rectDimensions.Top + 1;

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(borderPen, rectDimensions);

                // Draw the text content of the cell, ignoring alignment.
                if (e.Value != null)
                {
                    Brush textColor = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.ForeColor);

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font,
                        textColor, e.CellBounds.X +1,
                        e.CellBounds.Y + 3, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                }

                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

A good eye will still see it is not a perfect recreation, I would have to work with the format and alignment more for that, but it's pretty darn good that it is not worth my time getting it perfect.

And of course credit where it is due, got most of that code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx).

Surprised I haven't seen this linked as much when there are discussions about making borders or simply anything about modifying selected cells.